# Why is the Eclipse (IDE) naming history inconsistent?

Tags: eclipse, ide, naming-conventions

I know this is more of a meta programming question, but I'm not sure on which Stack Exchange platform I shall put this question on.

So, Wikipedia lists the following name history:

- Callisto
- Europa
- Ganymede
- Galileo
- Helios
- Indigo
- Juno
- Kepler
- Luna
- Mars
- Neon

Why are `D` and `F` missing? Aren't there any celestial names beginning with those letters? I can guess the naming convention didn't exist before Callisto, so that may be the reason `A` and `B` are missing.